# Tool for finding correlations between data after some event

Tags: correlation

I'm looking for a product that allows us to take in a collection of datastreams, and then after some event, will find any data that changes or correlates with that event. (For example, having a headache, and identifying that I drank too much beer last night and didn't drink enough water)

Comment: I think you'll probably need to be more specific about what your data is like, what your tool requirements are, what you've tried, in order to get more specific replies.